# boost::asio::async_write does not complete its task

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to figure out how asynchronous reads and writes work in boost asio by manipulating the echo example.  Currently, I have a server that should, when sent a sentence, respond with only the first word.  However, the boost::asio::async_write never seems to complete even though the write handler is being called.  Can someone please explain what's going on?  Here's the code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class session
{
public:
  session(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket_(io_service)
  {
  }

  tcp::socket& socket()
  {
    return socket_;
  }

  void start()
  {
 std::cout<<"starting"<<std::endl;
  boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_, buffer, ' ',
        boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }

  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
      size_t bytes_transferred)
  {

// std::ostringstream ss;
// ss<<&buffer;

 char* c = new char[bytes_transferred]; 

 //std::string s;
 buffer.sgetn(c,bytes_transferred);
 std::cout<<"data: "<< c<<" bytes: "<<bytes_transferred<<std::endl;

 if (!error)
    {
      boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
          boost::asio::buffer(c,bytes_transferred),
          boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
      delete this;
    }
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
 std::cout<<"handling write"<<std::endl;
    if (!error)
    {
    }
    else
    {
      delete this;
    }
  }

private:
  tcp::socket socket_;
  boost::asio::streambuf buffer;
};

class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
    : io_service_(io_service),
      acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
  {
    session* new_session = new session(io_service_);
    acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  void handle_accept(session* new_session,
      const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      new_session->start();
      new_session = new session(io_service_);
      acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
          boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
      delete new_session;
    }
  }

private:
  boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: async_tcp_echo_server <port>\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    using namespace std; // For atoi.
    server s(io_service, atoi(argv[1]));

    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're not using boost::asio::streambuf correctly, read the [HTTP client example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/async_client.cpp) closely.  For your code, you should do something like:

```
buffer.commit( bytes_transferred );
std::istream is( &buffer );
std::string data;
is >> data;
std::cout << "data: " << data << " bytes: " << bytes_transferred << std::endl;
```

then use a separate boost::asio::streambuf for your response. As the previous answer also said, you're leaking memory. I'd suggest using boost::shared_ptr and shared_from_this.

Comment: I know this is old but just FYI, there's absolutely nothing about calling commit on the buffer in the example you post to, so your comments and partial code are confusing.

Answer (score 0):

1. To avoid problems with possible memmory leaks involve with Session, You should consider using `boost::enable_shared_from_this`, like below:

   ```
   class session : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<session>
   ```

   Instead of use "this" use `shared_from_this()`.

   Don't use `delete this`.
2. You allocate table by `new` but I don`t see where memory is free.

   ```
   char* c = new char[bytes_transferred];
   ```

   `delete c` isn`t called
3. Maybe better solution is using additional buffer `m_bufferForRead` instead of allocate table `c`.

Answer (score -1):

As a could see you just don't close the socket and even don't delete the session.
After you successful write and complete write handler, you leave the session object making memory leak. Also the `char* c = new char[bytes_transferred];` make a memory leak as it is never used again, `boost::asio::buffer` don't  deallocate the memory for you.

Simply change the write handler:

```
void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
  std::cout<<"handling write and exiting."<<std::endl;
  delete this;
}
```

Comment: if i do that I just get an end of file exception

Comment: Where you get the exception from? For me this code run well (boost 1.40).